# How to use Selenium to input text in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to input "apple" instead of "hello" using Selenium in Python.

```
<span><div class="top1"><div class="top2"><label class="top3">
<label class="check"><input class="word" type="text" value="hello"></label>
```

How to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: I tried "driver.find_element_by_class_name('word')" but failed.

Comment: I will use send_keys() but I need to locate it first.

Comment: So the problem is not in *sending keys* but in *locating element*? You should update your question with correct description + your code + exception log

Comment: I certainly want to input text. It's just "driver.find_element_by_xpath('....').send_keys('apple')". But I don't know the first part.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('word')` should work - at least it will find element (it might be wrong element, but at least one found). If you got `NoSuchElementException` then it's not about xpath...

Comment: There is another input named "word". Can I use label class to locate the element?

Comment: Yes, you can use parent attributes to make your locator more specific

Comment: After finding the element, can I get its full xpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have provided, to send the text **apple** within the `<input>` element you can use the following code block :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='check']/input[@class='word' and @type='text' and @value='hello']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='check']/input[@class='word' and @type='text' and @value='hello']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='check']/input[@class='word' and @type='text' and @value='hello']").send_keys("apple")
```

Answer (score -1):

Before asking elementary questions like this, please read [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for tools which you are using. You can find documentation via Google.

About your task. First, you need find your input in source code, than clean value and input a new one.

```
your_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath to your input')
your_input.clear()
your_input.send_keys('your new text')
```